# custom font are not loaded in dialog's listView

Tags: android, xml, listview, textview, android-dialog

I have defined the font folder and xml file under drawable folder. I am using dialogue and defined the `List_view.xml` and `List_item.xml` for appearance of dialogue; However custom font defined in `list_item.xml`  is not loading at the time dialogue appears; default android font are showing.

I have tried to change the default font of the whole app but still dialogue loads default fonts.

[default-font-in-dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Icf.png)
[i want to use this font in dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxT81.png)

```
public void showDialogListView(View view) {


        dialog = new Dialog(personal_info_1.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
        dialog.setTitle("Select Country");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        //prepare a list view in dialog
        listview_country = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogList);


        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtitem, country_name);
        listview_country.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview_country.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(personal_info_1.this, "Clicked Item: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textview_country_info.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        dialog.show();
    }
```

here, `country_name` array in array adapter is fetched from database method in onCreate.

**list_item.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtitem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_light"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:background="@color/line_light"
/>
```

list_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dialogList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_background"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way here i posted please have a look on it.

You just remove the "android:fontfamily" element in textview of your "list_item.xml file"
and then do the following.

1.Create a font folder in res/font/ then
2.You just mention in the res/values/style.xml as like below- (just add the font family item to the resources)

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu_regular</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/ubuntu_regular</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu_regular</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/ubuntu_regular</item>
</style>
```

3.Then you just run the code this style.xml based font will automatically applies to whole application. You no need to add the fontfamily in anywhere in the application.

Comment: instead of "font/ubuntu_regular" you add your font file like "@font/<your font file>

Comment: I have tried as you said but not working. Still same problem. @Rajaji Subramanian

Comment: did you remove this line "android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_light" from your "list_item.xml"?

Comment: please check carefully once, because this is a 100% working solution which i have posted.

Comment: you not need to give typeface anywhere in application if you followed my way as am posted. even that custom font typeface will change the font in default alertdialog text  also

Comment: did you try this solution?

Comment: yes I have tried that in my app; it's not working; However, when I have made another separate app then it worked. Another thing is if I change the whole app's font and removed "fontfamily" from everywhere else, then also it didn't worked. @Rajaji Subramanian

Answer (score 0):

You can create CustomTextView class which Extend TextView and use that CustomTextView class in your .xml file instead of simple

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;


@SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView")
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {


    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/OpenSansSemiBold.ttf");
            this.setTypeface(face);
        }
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/OpenSansSemiBold.ttf");
            this.setTypeface(face);
        }
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/OpenSansSemiBold.ttf");
            this.setTypeface(face);
        }
    }
}
```

In Your .xml :

```
<app.com.packagename.CustomTextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
android:text="text"/>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Would be pleased if you could accept this answer.